# Prototyping tool that navigates back more than 1 level?

Tags: software-recommendation, prototyping

I'm currently using Invision to prototype apps/websites. Invision has a handy link that allows you to link back to whatever the previous screen was. However it only lets you do it for 1 level. So say for example I had a profile screen that could be accessed via 2+ levels of screens, this would not be possible to mock in invision. I would have to create a version of that profile screen for each specific branch.

Does anyone know of a better tool that can link back to previous screens past the most recent?

Comment: I don't think there is a tool that allows an interaction to trigger "going back in history" for more than one page. Have you considered the "series" screens in inVision?

Comment: You can always link directly back to that screen. But you won't be able to build stacks I am afraid.

Comment: @Aziz What do you mean by "series" screens? I have googled but still am not sure what you are referring to

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Indigo Studio](http://www.infragistics.com/products/indigo-studio) (they have a free trial). It's a bit more robust than InVision, but the way a project is structured with screen "states", it can support both a relative "back" along a single history path, or an absolute "back" that you can designate yourself with specific screen states.

This [interactions tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L5N3JoCwz6g) includes a couple different versions of "back" in their example, so you can see if it might support what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Principle ( only for mac ).
If you really want a lot more control try Adobe XD. 
I have  used Principle  a couple of times and it works great. Haven't used XD but it sure can help you out.

Comment: Could you tell us why you would recommend either software?